# Unity problems when my class is called from COM

Tags: .net, com, unity-container

Currently, I'm working in a solution that use Unity as a container for DI. This project contains a class that is visible to COM and expose one method.

When I Instance and use this class directly from a VS project all works fine, and If I use the class from a VS project using COM (CreateObject) it works well too.

Now, I've create a vbs file and I'm triying to create the class and call the method. The first problem was that Unity could not found the assembly Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration that was specified in the type attrib from the Section Tag of the XML coonfiguration file. I've resolved it putting Unity in the CAG and using the full qualified name of the assemby in the type attribute of the tag.

Now, Unity loads fine, but It can resolve my dependencies. Looks like It can't find the assemblies specified in the `<assembly>` tag (but I'm not sure).

I can't see what's happening, and I don't know why my code is working from a .net program and not from a vbs file.

**EDIT**:I've confirmed that UNITY is looking for the libraries in the wscript.exe folder, But I don't know how to change this behaviour.

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a configuration location problem. Since the application is runned by wscript.exe or cscript.exe, the framework looks for (w|c)script.exe.config ( I guess ) where you configured unity container, but you probably did not supply that file. Maybe is better to configure Unity programmatically in this case.

Comment: Thanks Felice. I'm making a proof of concept to see if configuring unity by code could solve the problem. I'm sure that the XML file is located and loaded when I call from COM (I debugged it using the old msgbox technique :D) but of course, maybe Unity is triying to find the assemblies in the same directory of that file... or in the wscript.exe folder.